# How to call C or CPP code in asm file [MSVC]?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, visual-c++, x86

I have a special program should be written in c and asm on **Windows platform**, I mean c and asm should call each other. There are so many asm code and MSVC don't support inline asm in x64, so I will not use inline asm format, all asm code written in asm file.

MSDN already show how to call asm code in C:

```
//asm
_f proc
...
...
_f endp

//c
extern "C" void f();
...
f();
```

But I can not find a document which explain how to call c code in asm.Like this:

```
//c
extern "C" void f()
{
//....
}

//asm
;how to declare f?

mov ..
mov ..
push ..
call f ??? how to ?
cmp eax,...
```

If MSVC can not do this , is there other asm compiler do this?

Comment: To call C from assembly, you need to know the calling convention and other ABI details with which the C was compiled. You then need to make sure you adhere to the calling convention. Particularly, you need to make sure to save all "scratch" registers you want to preserve across the function call yourself by pushing them on the stack and popping them off the stack when your call returns. You also need to make sure you pass the arguments in the order and positions expected. Etc.

Comment: What assembler do you use? MASM?

Comment: You do it the exact same way as C, you need to declare it `extern "C"` to disable mangling and then follow the same ABI.

Comment: @Louis Cloete  I use VS2019, I am not sure if it is called "MASM", I am learning it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/equ?view=msvc-160

Comment: You are using MASM then. Look at the url you pasted. I unfortunately do not know MASM, but NASM with System-V ABI.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any other asm compiler works for Win10?

Comment: Yes, all the major x86 assemblers work on Win10; NASM, FASM, MASM, GNU assembler, clang, etc.

Comment: MASM should be fine if you're already working with VS. Try searching for MASM call C function.

Comment: The easiest way to figure out how to do something in assembly is to do the same thing in C and then ask the C compiler to emit assembly code.  Read the assembly code emitted by the C compiler and do it the same way.  For i386 Windows, you'll probably have to use the cdecl calling convention.